# Passing urls to exec command in Ruby

Tags: ruby, shell

I need to call a shell command in Ruby, which receives an argument that is a URL. Here is how I am doing it:

```
output = `casperjs myscript.js #{url}`
```

However, if the URL contains weird parameters such as '(' or '|' I get errors from the shell. For example:

When passing '`https://www.theshadestore.com/window-treatments/product/solar-shade?preselected_collections[]=3-percent-basics&preselected_collections[]=5-percent-basics&preselected_collections[]=10-percent-basics`'

I get the following error:

```
sh: 1: preselected_collections[]=10-percent-basics: not found
sh: 1: preselected_collections[]=5-percent-basics: not found
```

And when I pass: '`http://www.coastal.com/nike-8206-200-brown?rsView=1&ga=F|M|K`'

I get:

```
sh: 1: M: not found
sh: 1: K: not found
```

How can I avoid that? I want that actually the whole URL is passed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the backticks execute their contained string with `/bin/sh`, so you probably want:

```
output = `casperjs myscript.js '#{url}'`
```

Comment: Just to clarify: If you don't put the url into quotes, it's parsed by the shell. Normally this works okay except that `&` and `|` have special meaning in the shell.

Answer (score 0):

i think this will work

`casperjs myscript.js "#{url}"`

When i tested in irb, it worked for one of the url's you have provided here